# Postgres select по полю

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.3
Есть 2 таблицы:

```
  1 табл  
    ид ! знач ! ид2(ВНЕШ КЛЮЧ)
    ____________
    1 ! 230   ! 23
    2 ! 240   ! 23
    3 ! 340   ! 24
    4 ! 350   ! 24
    ____________

    2 табл
    ид2! дата
    _____________
    23 ! 10.02
    34 ! 11.02
__________
```

Необходимо выбрать

```
дата  ! знач1! знач2 ! ид2
__________________________
10.02 ! 230  ! 240   ! 23
11.02 ! 340  ! 350   ! 24
```

Comment: дата в какой таблице?
сгруппировать по id чего?
что вы хотите получить в итоге?, в каком виде, проиллюстрируйте.

Comment: Эталон плохо заданного вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@anunak](/users/18372/anunak)](/users/18372/anunak), вам необходимо выполнить самое обычное внутреннее соединение (INNER JOIN) двух таблиц, про которое, вне всякого сомнения, можно прочитать [в документации PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) или любом справочнике по SQL, включая [статью на вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#INNER_JOIN).

Comment: сделал так http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/04/2-analizcreate-analizdata-scchemlog.html